# Get and set attribute value of d3.symbolTriangle

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using the d3.symbolTriangle to draw some equilateral triangle. I would like to know how is possible get and set the attribute values.

This is my code:

```
var body = d3.select("body");
var triangle = d3.symbol()
   .type(d3.symbolTriangle);
Group = [];

var svg = body.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("border", "1px solid black")
  .on("mousemove", function() {
    mouse = d3.mouse(this);
    isMouseMoving=true;
  });

function drawTriangles(number) {
  for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    Group[i] = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id",i);
    var dim = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800 + 50);
    var r = Math.random()*360;
    Group[i].append("path")
      .attr("d", triangle.size(dim))
      .attr("transform", function (d) {
        var boundingBox = this.getBBox();
        var elementWidth = Math.ceil(boundingBox.width);
        var randomXOffset = Math.random() * (width - elementWidth - 2 * borderSize) + elementWidth/2 + borderSize;
        var randomYOffset = Math.random() * (height - elementWidth - 2 * borderSize) + elementWidth/2 + borderSize;
            return "translate(" + randomXOffset + "," + randomYOffset + ")rotate("+r+")";
        })
      .attr("fill", "rgb(" + parseInt(Math.random() * 255) + "," + parseInt(Math.random() * 255) + "," + parseInt(Math.random() * 255) + ")")
      .attr("opacity", 2)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("proof", "Hello")
      .attr("radius", function() {
        return Math.sqrt(dim/(Math.sqrt(3)*3));
      });
  }
}
```

If I want to get the values of translate (the position of the triangle) or radius, and set a new values for example in a transition, how I can do?
I did something like:

```
Group[i]._groups[0][0].childNodes[0].attributes["radius"].nodeValue
```

but I don't think that this is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

In D3, a function like `attr` or `style` is both a setter and a getter. So, with two arguments it is a setter:

```
.attr("foo", bar);
```

And with just one argument it is a getter:

.attr("foo");

Given your code below...

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <body>
   <script>
    var width = window.innerWidth;
 var height = window.innerHeight;
 var number = 30;
 var body = d3.select("body");
 var triangle = d3.symbol()
    .type(d3.symbolTriangle);
 var margins = 20;
 var Group = [];
 var borderSize = 10;

var svg = body.append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
 .style("border", "1px solid black");


 function drawTriangles(number) {
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    Group[i] = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id",function(){ return "id" + i});
    var dim = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800 + 50);
    var r = Math.random()*360;
    Group[i].append("path")
      .attr("d", triangle.size(dim))
      .attr("transform", function (d) {
        var boundingBox = this.getBBox();
        var elementWidth = Math.ceil(boundingBox.width);
        var randomXOffset = Math.random() * (width - elementWidth - 2 * borderSize) + elementWidth/2 + borderSize;
        var randomYOffset = Math.random() * (height - elementWidth - 2 * borderSize) + elementWidth/2 + borderSize;
            return "translate(" + randomXOffset + "," + randomYOffset + ")rotate("+r+")";
        })
      .attr("fill", "rgb(" + parseInt(Math.random() * 255) + "," + parseInt(Math.random() * 255) + "," + parseInt(Math.random() * 255) + ")")
      .attr("opacity", 2)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("proof", "Hello")
      .attr("radius", function() {
        return Math.sqrt(dim/(Math.sqrt(3)*3));
      });
  }
}


drawTriangles(number);

var mytriangle = d3.select(d3.selectAll("#id5").select("path").node());

console.log(mytriangle.attr("fill"))
          
    </script>
  </body>
```

This is what you need to get the triangle within the group with ID number 5, for instance:

```
var mytriangle = d3.select(d3.selectAll("#id5").select("path").node());
```

And to get the fill of that triangle, you use `attr` as a getter:

```
console.log(mytriangle.attr("fill"))//returns rgb(128,141,30), which is a random value
```

To set new values you can just use the function as a setter, as you already did in your code. For example, in this snippet, we select the triangle withing the group with ID number 5 and translate it to 200,200:

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <body>
   <script>
    var width = window.innerWidth;
 var height = window.innerHeight;
 var number = 30;
 var body = d3.select("body");
 var triangle = d3.symbol()
    .type(d3.symbolTriangle);
 var margins = 20;
 var Group = [];
 var borderSize = 10;

var svg = body.append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
 .style("border", "1px solid black");


 function drawTriangles(number) {
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    Group[i] = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id",function(){ return "id" + i});
    var dim = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800 + 50);
    var r = Math.random()*360;
    Group[i].append("path")
      .attr("d", triangle.size(dim))
      .attr("transform", function (d) {
        var boundingBox = this.getBBox();
        var elementWidth = Math.ceil(boundingBox.width);
        var randomXOffset = Math.random() * (width - elementWidth - 2 * borderSize) + elementWidth/2 + borderSize;
        var randomYOffset = Math.random() * (height - elementWidth - 2 * borderSize) + elementWidth/2 + borderSize;
            return "translate(" + randomXOffset + "," + randomYOffset + ")rotate("+r+")";
        })
      .attr("fill", "rgb(" + parseInt(Math.random() * 255) + "," + parseInt(Math.random() * 255) + "," + parseInt(Math.random() * 255) + ")")
      .attr("opacity", 2)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("proof", "Hello")
      .attr("radius", function() {
        return Math.sqrt(dim/(Math.sqrt(3)*3));
      });
  }
}


drawTriangles(number);

var mytriangle = d3.select(d3.selectAll("#id5").select("path").node());

mytriangle.transition().delay(500).duration(5000).attr("transform", "translate(200,200)");
          
    </script>
  </body>
```

Now some problems in your code:

- IDs cannot start with a number
- "opacity" goes from 0 to 1
- paths don't have "radius".